# How to make a class template argument optional?

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any way to make a template class argument optional?
Specifically in this example:

```
template <typename EVT>
class Event : public EventBase {
public:             
    void raise(EVT data){
        someFunctionCall(data);
    }
}
```

I want to have a version of the same template equivalent to this:

```
class Event : public EventBase {
public:             
    void raise(){
        someFunctionCall();
    }
}
```

But I don't want to duplicate all the code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With default template argument, and template specialization :

```
template <typename EVT=void>
class Event : public EventBase {
public:             
    void raise(EVT data){
        someFunctionCall(data);
    }
};

template <>
class Event<void> : public EventBase {
public:             
    void raise(){
        someFunctionCall();
    }
};
```

However, I don't see how would the EventBase look like.

Comment: Note that this does require you to redefine all the members, or move them to a shared base class.

Comment: Also note that instantiating the specialization has an unexpected syntax: `Event<> MyEvent;`

Comment: @MooingDuck I was just going to ask that!

Comment: Another option is to make the default a non-template class.

Comment: @VJo: it would have to have a different name then.